# How do I stop Javascript accessing Flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash

We have a website with a lot of Flash content on, and it would be unrealistic to modify all of that content. The problem we have is that Javascript can access variables in the Flash content that we actually don't want the user to have access to using:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('object'))[0]).GetVariable("secret"):
```

And then either Alerting that or even changing another element on the page to display 'secret' variable.

The question is, how do we stop users accessing the object via Javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How "unrealistic" are we talking here? Because more bad design practices is rarely a good idea to solve bad design practices.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: anything that's running on the client is out of your hands entirely. If you're doing something top secret there, that's already a fail.

Comment: The content will be updated eventually, but it is important that we sort something out short term. Is there nothing in the Flash object tag that stops Javascript interacting with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an AcionScript class file and declaring the stuff inside private.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f32.html

Comment: We cannot really effect the content as it is we can only place it in some sort of wrapper.